# Why is this CompletionStage code causing a compilation error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-8

I have two class;say A and B; both returning CompletionStage. 
**class B code:**

```
class B {
    public CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>> m1(SampleObject1 obj) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dosomething(obj))
            .thenApplyAsync(results ->
                Optional.ofNullable((results.length == 1) ? results : null)
            );
    }
}
```

**class A code:**

```
class A {
    public CompletionStage<Optional<SampleObject2>> m2(Optional<DynamicForm> dynamicForm) {
        CompletionStage<DynamicForm> promiseOfFormData = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dynamicForm.get());

        CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>> c = promiseOfFormData.thenApplyAsync(
            data -> b.m1(new SampleObject1(data.get("key1"), data.get("key2")))
        );
        return something.....;
    }
}
```

However, it's throwing following error at runtime:

```
inference variable U has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Optional<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>
    lower bounds: java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<java.util.Optional<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are trying to return a `CompletableFuture<CompletionStage<Optional<UserOutDetails>>>` where the declared return type is `CompletionStage<Optional<SampleObject2>>`. Of course, that doesn’t work.

Comment: @Abhinab, I took the liberty to rollback your last edit, as the accepted answer better matches the original question than your tentative at fixing it. I hope it's fine for you.

Comment: @Didier, sure no issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your return types:

```
b.m1(new SampleObject1(data.get("key1"), data.get("key2")))
```

is returning a `CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>>` as from the method signature in `B`, so

```
data -> b.m1(new SampleObject1(data.get("key1"), data.get("key2")))
```

is of type `Function<DynamicForm,CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>>>` and the following

```
promiseOfFormData.thenApplyAsync(
    data -> b.m1(new SampleObject1(data.get("key1"), data.get("key2")))
);
```

is thus of type `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>>>` which is incompatible with the target type `CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>>`. The error you have is in the computation of the bounds of the target type.

What you should do instead is probably use [`CompletionStage#thenComposeAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenComposeAsync-java.util.function.Function-), which is designed for functions that also return a `CompletionStage`:

```
CompletionStage<Optional<Map<String, Object>>> c = promiseOfFormData.thenComposeAsync(
    data -> b.m1(new SampleObject1(data.get("key1"), data.get("key2")))
);
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite `m1` to not create a `CompletionStage` but just perform the computation, and then use it in a `thenApplyAsync` call as you were previously doing.

Comment: edited class A as per your suggestion. Pleas/e look at the class A code. But error still exists. Can you please help me

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar I have added a proposed solution inside my answer, based on the original code. However you shouldn't modify your questions with follow-up questions or with answers. You should also pay attention to your code formatting, as people won't read poorly formatted questions (I had already edited the formatting before you modified it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. using thenComposeAsync. working now :)